# What does Ops stand for?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In Scala community I see often, that classes end with `Ops` are very common. For example:

```
ApplicativeErrorIdOps
```

What does `Ops` stand for?

Comment: FWIW this usage isn't Cats-specific—see e.g. `scala.collection.ArrayOps` in the standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ops = Operations. This is quite commonly used shortcut not only in Scala but in general.

In Cats it's used as a suffix of an extension methods class because it enriches the value with operations related to some type class.